# Headphones recognized as Headset

Tags: pulseaudio, jack, alsamixer

When I plug in my headphone into the (only, so pobably combined out/in) jack in my laptop in Ubuntu 20.04 the config switches output to headphone (I like that) and mic to the non-existing headphone mic (not so).

I can switch the mic back to internal laptop mic in the settings, but it's quite tiring since I plug/unplug them often.

The jack of the headphone has three sections (not four as proper headsets have).

How do I prevent switching to the non-existing mic?

I tried [Changing PulseAudio Source port: 'availability=no' and priority](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305183/changing-pulseaudio-source-port-availability-no-and-priority) but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

A combination jack to support headphones, headset or microphone can be retasked to disable the microphone connection in ALSA

If the jack socket is only recognised a headphone connection, the jack-detection function will not change the PulseAudio microphone Port

1. Install package `alsa-tools` (if not already installed)
2. Run the retasking tool from a terminal with root privileges
   `sudo hdajackretask`
3. Find the Pin connection relating to the external microphone, enable the **Override** option and select 'Not Connected' from the drop-down menu

[image]

4. click <kbd>Install Boot Override</kbd>
5. Reboot system and check PulseAudio detects headphone output but not microphone input
   `pacmd list-cards`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. At first I had to install `alsa-tools-gui` so I could run `hdajackretask`. But only the headset was available, not the mic. So there was nothing to turn off.

Comment: hdajackretask would usually show a connection for headphones and microphone and could not show multiple pins combined as a headset. My thinking was to use hdajackretask to disable the microphone connection on the TRRS jack so it only supports a TRS headphone connection jack, so PulseAudio could not switch to a microphone Port if it is not recognised

Comment: You are right, it says "Black Headphone, Front side", not headset. But besides the Internal Mic and Internal Speaker I don't have the Mic in the list. Thanks for your idea though!